# SQL Profiler 2008 Deadlock Graph ToolTip Not Showing actual statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

In a deadlock graph, hovering over the deadlock ovals should produce the SQL statement. However, in SQL Profiler 2008, the ToolTip is either showing "Statement" or "Statement Proc" and not the statement itself. Does anyone ? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Does the raw XML contain the statements? (Use the "Extract Event Data" to save as XML)

Comment: Is your trace also collecting StmtCompleted events? This article has a good primer: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/

Comment: Do you run encrypted procedures, or does your batch contain passwords?

Comment: @Martin - I will try that and report back

Comment: @Aaron - Unfortunately I need to catch this in a production environment so switching on StmtCompleted will flood my profiler.

Comment: @Martin. kudos for you. That worked. Please submit that as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why these wouldn't show up in the graphic itself. Perhaps worth reporting as a bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback).

As a workaround you could try using the "Extract Event Data" option to save as XML and look for them there.